# Google translated page renders unusable site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-translate

Up until recently, this site functioned fine when translated in Google. Now, when translating a page, links don't work/are changed, styles are ignored or overridden, the menu no longer works, scripts seem crippled and in general it's a mess, with no apparent (to me) logical explanation.

http://stage.ladottransit.com/index_gt.html

Click translate and choose any language.

In the translated page, if you click the menu button, and then click one of the list items, it should expand a submenu. It does not. Initially I had heard that using a hash link can cause this (using JQuery for the nav, amongst other things, and this requires the list headers to link to `#`), so I changed those to `javascript:;`, to no avail.

Lazy loaded images never show up, even though inspecting the styles says they are displayed and at full opacity. As they are in a carousel, they are floated left and `overflow:hidden`. They also lay over the top of the page content so that none of it is clickable. I need to get this back to a state where it functions reasonably in other languages as soon as possible.

My JS skills are pretty remedial, so if this comes down to a script conflict with something at Google, the odds that I will be able to suss it on my own are not great. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you checking for  errors in your developer/javascript console? There are a tonne of errors for you to explore. The "chromeextension://chromecast" ones should be ignored as this is a google issue that doesn't actually cause any problems for you... also I am seeing this http://imgur.com/iHYYLRd ... perhaps you can disable safe mode somehow

Comment: I'm doing the console thing right now. Besides the chrome extension, I'm only getting one error:

Comment: oops... here's the error in the console. 

`translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=en&tl=es&u=http://stage.ladottransit.com/ind…:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://stage.ladottransit.com/whatsnew/alerts.html. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

I tried adding `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` but that didn't help.

Comment: Also, I did try safe mode, but get the same result.